# Signal R server in Asp.net Web From

Tags: asp.net, signalr

i know there are lot of SignalR Server sample in Asp.net MVC ,winform ,Console ,Window Service .

But i have not find any signalr server  sample in Asp.net Web Page.

The situation is that i have make SignalR Client application in Console . and now i need make server Application in Asp.net web page .i don't know how to start its,i am new in that .

i know my question is bit wired. please just tell if there is any link with updated signalR version.

Thanks Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this , you'll able to understand that how to start. you just need map your hub in server asp.net index.html page

[Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/637762/ASP-NET-SignalR-Basis-Step-by-Step-Part)

hope this help .